# How To Make A Device Automatically Add Itself To A Meeting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, azure

In short: how can I have a device automatically add itself to a meeting booked in Outlook, when the selected location of the meeting is the room which contains the device?

Further info:
In our office we have a Surface Hub v1. We have set up a working device account with the Surface Hub, and we also have a separate Location mailbox for the room it is in. Both accounts work fine separately, but I have been tasked with making the Surface Hub get an automatic invite when its room is booked on Outlook. That is, you don't have to add the Surface Hub to the meeting: as soon as you choose its room as the meeting location, and confirm the meeting, it automatically adds itself.

I thought about making a shared mailbox that encompasses the room and the Hub, but this doesn't seem like the right way to go about it. Does anyone have any ideas? (I have full admin privileges for our 365 Admin site, so there's no permission problems.)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could create a transport rule to add the Surface mailbox to the ‘TO’ box when the meeting sent to the Room:
[image]
It is better to set the resource mailbox to accept meeting request automatically, you could run below command to configure it:

Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity "resource mailbox" -AutomateProcessing AutoAccept

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful.  
If an Answer is helpful, please mark the helpful replies as answers.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem perfectly . Perhaps in the future I will consider using Teams Rooms. This is a perfect solution for now. (Sorry, I'm new to Stack Exchange and not sure of the etiquette. Shortly after you posted last week, I clicked the up arrow to mark as Useful. I didn't want to mark as Answered until I got it working).

Comment: It is OK. I am glad to know this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider switching that room mailbox into a [Microsoft Teams Room](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/rooms/rooms-deploy). Would solve a lot.